# azure computer vision detect text

Tags: azure

I'm using azure computer vision to extract text from images and it works as expected, but now I'm facing a challenge where I have to retrieve just a specific text and not all text from the image, and the text that I would like to extract maybe be different from one image to another.(and maybe these images could have a common text)
is there a way at Azure computer vision could help me to do that please ?
example : the ingredient because there are a lot photos with ingredients mixed with simple text how can i extract just the ingredients :
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you share an example image? How do you determine what part is the "specific text" that should be extracted if it differs from image to image?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, for example ingredients of a product

Comment: post updated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Azure Cognitive Service Vision API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/computervision/3.1/recognize-printed-text/recognize-printed-text) is capable of detecting contiguous text as a "region", a region consists of "lines" and lines contain "words". A simply approach would be detecting if a certain keyword (like "ingredients") appears in a region and if so, save all words that appear after the keyword in the same region (using Levenshtein distance to allow some deviation):

```py
import requests
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import Levenshtein  # install with pip install python-Levenshtein

def draw_bounding_box(ax, coordinates, color, size):
    coordinates_array = coordinates.split(",")
    x = int(coordinates_array[0])
    y = int(coordinates_array[1])
    w = int(coordinates_array[2])
    h = int(coordinates_array[3])
    try:
        rect = patches.Rectangle((x, y), w, h, linewidth=size, edgecolor=color, facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
    except:
        pass

def text_detection(service_endpoint, subscription_key, filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
    params = {'language': 'fr', 'detectOrientation': 'false'}
    response = requests.post(service_endpoint, headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

    analysis = response.json()
    regions = analysis['regions']

    im = np.array(Image.open(filename), dtype=np.uint8)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.imshow(im)
    ingredients = ""

    for region in regions:
        in_ingredients = False
        draw_bounding_box(ax, region["boundingBox"], "g", 3)
        for line in region["lines"]:
            draw_bounding_box(ax, line["boundingBox"], "b", 2)
            for word in line["words"]:
                text = word["text"]
                if Levenshtein.distance(text.lower(), "ingredients") <= 2:
                    in_ingredients = True
                if in_ingredients:
                    ingredients += text + " "

    plt.show()
    print(ingredients)

service_endpoint = "https://<region>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.1/ocr"
subscription_key = "<your key>"
image_path = "/path/to/image.jpg"

text_detection(service_endpoint, subscription_key, image_path)
```

Output (green bounding box is the region, blue the lines):

[image]

```
INGRÉDIENTS : Nouilles 88 % : farine de blé ; huile de palme amidon modifié de pomme de terre ; sel , poudres à lever E500,E501. Assaisonnement 12 % : sel ; exhausteurs degoù g\utamate monosodique, E635 ; maltodextrine , sucre, carotte lactose ; curry 5 % (curcuma, cumin, cannelle, fenugrec, muscade, cardamome, clou de girofle, gingembre, piment, coriandre, poivre noir) ; extrait de poulet en poudre arômes (dont blé, lait) ; curcuma en poudre ; poireau 2,2 asse de poulet ; extrait de levure ; ail en poudre ; saucede sojaen poudre (soja, blé, maltodextrine, sel) ; ciboulette deshydratée % ; coriandre en poudre ; Piment ; poivrenar colorants : extrait de paprika, E150c. de céleri, crustacés, mollusques, moutarde, œufs, Poissons, graines de sésame et sulfites
```

Another example:

[image]

```
INGREDIENTS: WATER, TOMATO PASTE), SUGAR! SOYBEAN OIL, DISTILLED OF: MODIÅED CORN STARCH, DEHYDRATED ONION, PHOSPHORIC ACID, XANTHAN GUM, NATURAL FLAVOR, DEHYDRATED GARLIC, POTASSIUM SORBATE AND CALCIUM DISODIUM EDTA (PRESERVATIVES), CITRIC ACID, GUAR GUM, RED 40, YELLOW 6, BLUE 1. OUR PROMISE, QUALITY & SATISFACTION 100% GUARANTEED OR YOUR MONEY BACK
```

This approach is not bulletproof for sure. It will fail if the keyword appears in another portion of the text or if the ingredients table is divided like in this example:

[image]

```
ingredient to be naturally derived if it is unchanged from its natural state or has undergone processing yet still retains greater than 50% of its molecular structure from its original plant or mineral source. This formula consists of 96% naturally derived ingredients
```

Comment: Hi @chritian, thank you so much for the explications, I was thinking in this approach, but the problem is, there are some images do not contain the key word ingredients, they contain just simple text in the form of ingredients...do you see the challenge ?

Comment: is there the javascript version of this code please ?

Comment: You could expand the list of keywords of ingredients that you expect to appear frequently (e.g. "water") and if at least X of those keywords are present, we assume it is an ingredient table.

Comment: Yes Thinks I understand, but I'm using Nodejs and not Python, is there a javascript version of that  please?

Comment: any news about javascript code please ?

Comment: Christian I made a new post if you could help please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045911/azure-computer-vision-recognize-printed-text